# Why can't I use law of total expectation here?

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be iid from $U(0,2)$. What's $E[|−|]$?

I tried simulating the answer, and I got 2/3. I was wondering why this method below, which uses linearity of conditional expectation, doesn't work:
\begin{align}
E[|X-Y|]&=E[X-Y|X>Y]\\
&=\int_0^2E[X-Y|X>Y,Y=y]f_Y(y)dy\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^2E[X-Y|X>Y,Y=y]dy\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^2(E[X|X>Y,Y=y]-E[Y|X>Y,Y=y])dy\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^2\left(\frac{2+y}{2}-y\right)dy\\
&=1/2.
\end{align}
Which differs from the correct answer, 2/3.

Comment: Not sure if this counts, but when you write $E[X-Y | X > Y]$, this is already defined as $\int_{X > Y} X-Y f_{XY}(x,y)dx\;dy/\int_{X > Y}f_{XY}(x,y)dx\;dy$, where $f_{XY}$ is the joint density of $X,Y$. It is definitely the second equality where things go awry: we are looking at the sigma algebra generated by $X>Y$ and $Y = y$, but I don't think this has the uniform density $f_Y(y) = 1/2$. I think you would expect the conditional density of $Y$ on the set $X > Y$ to be concentrated around $Y = 0$ and small around $y = 2$, which is not what you have.

Comment: But why can't I also calculate $E[X-Y|X>Y]$ with the law of total expectation?

Comment: You probably can, what I am saying is that $f_{Y|X > Y}(y) \neq 1/2$ on the set $X > Y$, the density $Y = y$ should be $(2-y)/2$. To see this look at the triangle on $[0,2] \times [0,2]$ given by $X > Y$, and take the marginal density of $Y$.

Comment: The correct expression is: $E[X-Y|X>Y]=\int_0^2E[X-Y|X>Y,Y=y]dP_{Y/X>Y}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the equation $$E(X-Y\mid X>Y) = \int_0^2 E(X-Y\mid X>Y, Y=y)f_Y(y) dy.$$

Recall that the law of total expectation comes from partitioning the sample space: $$ E(X) = \int_\Omega X(\omega)d\omega = \sum_i \int_{E_i} X(\omega) d\omega = \sum_i E(X;E_i) = \sum_i E(X\mid E_i) P(E_i).$$ If we're already conditioning on something, the relationship we can write down is $$ \begin{align}E(X\mid E) &= \frac{1}{P(E)} E(X;E) \\&= \frac{1}{P(E)}\int_E X(\omega) d\omega \\&= \frac{1}{P(E)} \sum_i E(X;E\cap E_i)\\&=\frac{1}{P(E)} \sum_i E(X\mid E\cap E_i)P(E\cap E_i)\end{align}.$$

So the thing you want to integrate against is not $f_Y(y)$ (analogous to $P(E_i)$) but rather something analogous to $P( (X>Y)\cap (Y=y)).$ Or, rather, since we can bring the $\frac{1}{P(E)}$ inside the sum and write $$ E(X\mid E) = \sum_i E(X\mid E\cap E_i)P(E_i\mid E),$$ we want to integrate against the conditional $P(Y=y\mid X>Y),$ which if we permit ourselves some more informal manipulations, is given by

$$P(Y=y\mid X>Y)= \frac{P(X>y\mid Y=y)P(Y=y)}{P(X>Y)} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}(2-y)\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}} = 1-\frac{y}{2}.$$

So, your $$ \int_0^2 \left(1-\frac{y}{2}\right)\frac{1}{2}dy= \frac{1}{2}$$ becomes $$ \int_0^2\left(1-\frac{y}{2}\right)^2dy=\frac{2}{3}.$$